# Unable to install python2.7-dev on Raring

Tags: python, ubuntu-13.04

I am trying to do it through ubuntu software center and I get this message:

```
python2.7-dev: Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.4-2ubuntu3) but 2.7.4-2ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
           Depends: libpython2.7-dev (= 2.7.4-2ubuntu3) but 2.7.4-2ubuntu3 is to be installed
           Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.4-2ubuntu3) but 2.7.4-2ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this.  From here [ubuntu forum for same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275861/problem-installing-python-dev)

I used:

```
echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raring-updates.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```